# Api platform - remove auto code response description from swagger

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I've a endpoint in POST method with custom controller and I only described **200** code response in my **YAML** file. But when I look my swagger doc I can show 201, 400 and 422 code reponse. How can I remove them ?

Answer (score 2):

I am late, but this worked for me: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#configuring-operations

In config/api_platform/resources.yaml, I have added:

```
App\Entity\CriteriaDeleteChatRooms:
collectionOperations:
  post:
    status: 200
```

After doing this, the status code has been updated from 201 to 200.

Comment: Thanks ! code 200 is ok but not 400 and 422. It's a cutomer controller with custom input and I get this on Swagger: **422 Unprocessable entity